# change Width Gridview While  containing 100 words;

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   GridLines="Vertical" Width="825px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyleWidth="1"
            SortExpression="Body"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" 
    Select="new (Title, Body)" TableName="PrivateMessages">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Code

```
GridView1.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = 1;
```

i would like Fixed Columns[1].width=1 ; While `Body` containing 100 words;

This Code Does Not Change Width Gridview?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to change the `GridView` with drag and drop.  You have to just select its edges and you can change it.

Comment: i like fixed column for user.

Comment: ya you can select gridview after that you have to select edit coloum and in that u have to select colum accoring to your requirement and if you want to extra field in that u can easily add that.......